# Android - set button text from Fragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-button

I created new project with **Navigation Drawer Activity** template in Android Studio 2.2.2. I decided to use **FrameLayout**, so as i click on navigation menu item, new fragment loads.

In my **content_main.xml** i have FrameLayout element like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

That is Frame where the content will be shown.

Then i have layout **fragment_one.xml** and its class **FragmentOne** and they look like this:

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<Button
    android:text="Default Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mybutton" />
```

**FragmentOne class**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    Button btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        return view;
    }

    public void changeBtnText(String txt)
    {
        btn.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

In **MainActivity**'s onCreate() method i have code:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentOne()).commit();

    FragmentOne fragment_obj = (FragmentOne)getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.frOne);
    fragment_obj.changeBtnText("Changed text");
```

Here i get error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.user.myapplication.FragmentOne.changeBtnText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

How I can change fragment's **Button text** from Main Activity by using changeBtnText(String txt) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call changeBtnText(String txt) inside fragment not in the activity.

**EDIT:**

**inside FragmentOne.class**

```
public FragmentOne newInstance(String text) {
    FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne ();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("text", text);
    fragmentOne .setArguments(args);

    return fragmentOne ;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

    String text = getArguments().getString("text", null);
    changeBtnText(text);

    return view;
}
```

**in the Activity**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentOne.newInstance("text")).commit();
```

Comment: U should clearly define what and when to show text in ur question. I assumed you wanna change the text according to the clicked nav item. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: And the title says "set button text from Fragment in Activity". But what u are doing in the code is to set text in Fragment from the Activity

Comment: Sorry, but yout updated code doesn't work for me. I want to call a method changeBtnText(String txt) in Activity.

Comment: @Hawkridge You can't. The button isn't available until the Fragment is created and layout is inflated. Using arguments, as this answer does is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created the `Fragment`, which is why it's null. You create a new one in line but don't save it.

Try this;

```
FragmentOne fragment_obj = new FragmentOne();
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentOne).commit();

fragment_obj.changeBtnText("Changed text");
```